# Mockito.verify() in Groovy causing ambiguous method error for a Spring @MockBean

Tags: spring, groovy, mockito

I am trying to verify that a method was called on a Spring `@MockBean`:

```
Mockito.verify(rabbit).convertAndSend(
        Mockito.isA(String.class),
        Mockito.isA(String.class),
        Mockito.isA(Object.class)
)
```

I am doing this in a Spock test, and getting the following error:

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Ambiguous method overloading for method org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate$MockitoMock$2020468097#convertAndSend.
Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [null, null, null] due to overlapping prototypes between:
    [class java.lang.String, class java.lang.Object, interface org.springframework.amqp.core.MessagePostProcessor]
    [class java.lang.Object, interface org.springframework.amqp.core.MessagePostProcessor, class org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CorrelationData]
    ... 1 more
```

Is there a better way to use Mockito syntax to point it to the particular method?

Comment: `Mockito.isA(...)` returns `null`.  Is that really what you want to pass as arguments to `convertAndSend`?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown, of course not, I just meant to verify that convertAndSend() is called with any arguments. What is the right way to do it?

Comment: "I just meant to verify that convertAndSend() is called with any arguments" - Which version of the overloaded versions of `convertAndSend` do you want to be called?

Comment: Have you tried `Mockito.any(...)` instead?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate#convertAndSend(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)

Comment: @crizzis yes, with the same effect

Comment: @jjarzynski Any time you are passing nulls to an overloaded method with the same number of parameters, without static type checking in place (which you likely don't want in this context), the runtime can't possibly know which of the methods you intended to invoke.  If you cast the `null` values, then the runtime can select the desired method.

Comment: Casting with `Mockito.verify(rabbit).convertAndSend(ArgumentMatchers.isA(String) as String, ArgumentMatchers.isA(String) as String, ArgumentMatchers.isA(Object) as Object)` produces the same error.